# jQuery rotator always snaps back to the first image

Tags: jquery, image, fadeout, rotator

It's rather simple, after the last child img, the code snaps back to the first one, and for some reason fadeOut effect doesn't occur.

Here's HTML:

```
<div id="reel">
<img src="http://www.myweddingflowerideas.co.uk/wedding-flowers.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.aumflowersindiaflorists.com/images/flowers-chennai-1.jpg" />
<img src="http://img4.sunset.com/i/2008/12/image-adds-1217/alcatraz-flowers-galliardia-m.jpg?300:300" />
<img src="http://www.flowerslebanondelivery.com/catalog/images/Val101.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.weddingfloweridea.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/wedding-flowers-11.jpg" />
<img src="http://flowershopsflowers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Cardinal-Flowers.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#reel img{
position:absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#reel img:lt(5)").hide();
var counter = $("#reel img").length-1;

var i = setInterval(function() {

           $("#reel img").eq(counter).show();    
        $("#reel img").eq(counter - 1).show();
        $("#reel img").eq(counter).fadeOut(2000);
        counter--;

        if (counter === 0) {
            counter = 5;
        }
    }, 4000);

});
```

Check out this fiddle to see the problem in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/FB9a9/

All that I want is the last image to fadeOut onto the first one, without snapping to it, so is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you get to the end (0th image), the next image( 5th) comes after it in the markup, giving it a higher stacking order.  Calling show() makes it visible on top and the other image fadeOut()s behind it.  You may want to pull the img elements out of #reel and store them in an array, only adding them when they are being displayed.

Comment: any suggestion how to add them in array? Working example would be much appreciated.